# Finding limit of $\left(\frac{n^2 + n}{n^2 + n + 2}\right)^n$

Tags: limits

Please, help me to find limit of this sequence:
$\lim_{n\to \infty} \left(\frac{n^2 + n}{n^2 + n + 2}\right)^n$

Comment: Just out of curiosity: what is the $6$ in the question title for? :)

Comment: The 6 is for unique title of question ;)

Comment: Ah, you mean you want to differentiate this one from others for the ease of searching, right?

Comment: Awful option. Better to include some specifics of the question in the title. More importantly, *where is your personal input?*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have
$$
\bigg( \frac{n^{2}+n}{n^{2}+n+2} \bigg)^{n}
=
\bigg( 1 + \frac{2}{n^{2}+n} \bigg)^{-n}
=
\exp \bigg[ -n \log \bigg( 1 + \frac{2}{n^{2}+n}\bigg) \bigg]
=
\exp \bigg( \frac{-2}{n+1} - \frac{2}{n+1}o(1) \bigg)
\to e^{0}
= 1
$$
as $n \to \infty$.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint.** Notice that: $$\forall n\in\mathbb{N},\frac{n^2+n}{n^2+n+2}=1-\frac{2}{n^2+n+2}.$$
And now, remind that: $$\forall n\in\mathbb{N},\left(\frac{n^2+n}{n^2+n+2}\right)^n=\exp\left[n\ln\left(\frac{n^2+n}{n^2+n+2}\right)\right].$$

Answer (score 0):

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(\frac{n^2+n}{n^2+n+2}\right)^n=$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\exp\left(\ln\left(\left(\frac{n^2+n}{n^2+n+2}\right)^n\right)\right)=$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\exp\left(n\ln\left(\frac{n^2+n}{n^2+n+2}\right)\right)=$$
$$\exp\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}n\ln\left(\frac{n^2+n}{n^2+n+2}\right)\right)=$$
$$\exp\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln\left(\frac{n^2+n}{n^2+n+2}\right)}{\frac{1}{n}}\right)=$$
$$\exp\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}n}\left(\ln\left(\frac{n^2+n}{n^2+n+2}\right)\right)}{\frac{\text{d}}{\text{d}n}\left(\frac{1}{n}\right)}\right)=$$
$$\exp\left(\lim_{n\to\infty}-\frac{2n(2n+1)}{(n+1)(n^2+n+2)}\right)=$$

---

Since $-2n(2n+1)$ grows asymptotically slower than $(n+1)(n^2+n+2)$ as $n$ approaches $\infty$:

---

$$\exp\left(0\right)=e^0=1$$

Answer (score 0):

Write the expression as

$$\left [ \left ( 1 + \frac{2}{n^2 +n}\right)^{(n^2+n)/2} \right ]^{(2n)/(n^2+n)}.$$

As $n \to \infty,$ the term inside the brackets $\to e,$ and the outer exponent $\to 0.$ The limit is therefore $e^0 = 1.$